# NS Array index beyond bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opencv, ios-simulator

Working under iOS with XCode 5.1.1 and iOS-Simulator 7.1, the following error occurs whenever I try to read more than 43 images in a vector-array (see screenshot below):
[image: screenshot error message]

My code looks like this :

```
int num_pict = 52;
std::vector<cv::Mat> image_test(num_pict);
for (int i = 0; i < num_pict; i++) {
    // Read image mat
    image_test[i] = [in_image_array[i] CVMat];
}
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: what is the count of your array?

Comment: use this `int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It would resolve the issue. You are trying to access 43 rd index but in array there are only 0 - 42 indexes available

```
int num_pict = 43;
std::vector<cv::Mat> image_test(num_pict);
for (int i = 0; i < num_pict; i++) {
    // Read image mat
    image_test[i] = [[in_image_array[i] CVMat];
}
```

Comment: This works ! Thanks a lot. (oh dear! - I just realized that the "in_image_array" did not collect more than 43 images. Easy now! I was looking way too far... Thanks again for the help and sorry about this very simple issue...)